# Can I define all import in one file in python shell

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to import multiple imports in one module, and then import that module and have everything I need imported. Can I do that?

I'm trying it like this:

```
>>> os.system('cat python_imports.py')    # just to show the contents of a file
import sys
0
>>> import python_imports    # now import
>>> sys            #  now use the imported stuff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

So what to do if this doesn't work?

If someone didn't understand the question: When working with python shell; I'm using some same modules everytime, which need to be imported manualy. I don't want to import the same modules every time I start Python shell, I want to import them faster. 
So is there any way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good way to do this and if we knew exactly what you were trying to accomplish, we could suggest a better solution.

Comment: `from python_imports import *`

Comment: "Can I do that?" - no, because you'll have circular import problems out the wazoo, even if you get the syntax right. "So what to do if this doesn't work?" - have each module import what it needs.

Comment: @user2357112 - I didn't see any circular imports. I think OP just wants to speed up work in the shell by having the stuff he's working on in a single import file.

Comment: @tdelaney: In interactive mode, it might succeed. In a program with multiple files, trying to stuff all imports into one file is going to cause circular imports.

Comment: @user2357112 - I don't see how that's a problem either. You can do it wrong, but you don't have to. Its considered bad form by some (modules should be more explicit) but its done all the time in `__init__.py` packages.

Comment: @tdelaney: That's exporting the package's contents for outside use. You don't have all the submodules trying to `import *` from `__init__.py`.

Comment: Trying to shove everything you export into one file works fine. Trying to shove all your imports into one file and have all the other files `import *` from that file is a recipe for circular import disaster.

Comment: @user2357112 - you are persistent, I'll grant you that. It was just an example (and they can indeed pull in other modules). Suppose I'm running a build server with many small tasks. I may supply multiple helper modules and those may be little more than convenient importers of other modules. I know this works because I've done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want a convenient way to import modules into a shell session without a lot of tedious typing.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> open('python_imports.py').read()
'import sys\n\n'
>>> from python_imports import *
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>>
```

Comment: I didn't even try because to me it seemed to simple to work. But it does work, thanks!